# Inequality with supremum of divergence of vector fields

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum, geometric-measure-theory

I would like to write this inequality:

$$\sup\left\{ \int_{A \cup (\mathbb{R}^d \setminus F)} \operatorname{div} T \space \rm d m^d : T \in C_0^1(\mathbb{R}^d,\mathbb{R}^d), |T(x)| \le 1 \right\} \le \\ \le \sup\left\{ \int_A \operatorname{div} T \space \rm d m^d : T \in C_0^1(\mathbb{R}^d,\mathbb{R}^d), |T(x)| \le 1 \right\} +\\ +\sup \left\{ \int_{\mathbb{R}^d \setminus F} \operatorname{div} T \space dm^d : T \in C_0^1(\mathbb{R}^d,\mathbb{R}^d),|T(x)| \le 1 \right\}$$

Where $\operatorname{div} T$ is the divergence of the field $T$ and $A,F \subset \mathbb{R}^d$. 
The problem is when the divergence is negative. But, in my opinion, when I consider the supremum, if $T$ is one candidate then also $-T$ is, and so I can consider field that have positive divergence, for the regularity of that field in which I take the supremum.

Comment: No, you cannot do that: if you replace $T$ by $-T$, then when you eliminate the sign the inequality will transform from $\leq$ into $\geq$, precisely the opposite of what you want.

Comment: @Alex M. ok. so this inequality can't hold?

Comment: No, I only said that your method would not work; the inequality is trivially true, there is nothing to prove. In general, if $(x_i)_{i \in I}$ and $(y_i)_{i \in I}$ are two families of real numbers, then $\sup (x_i + y_i) \leq \sup x_i + \sup y_i$.

Comment: @AlexM. Thanks.

Comment: @AlexM. Sorry, but there is one thing that is not clear for me. If the supremum is negative, and the two set are not disjoint, I don't think that the equality hold...

Comment: We have that $x_i + y_i \leq x_i + \sup y_i$, therefore $\sup (x_i + y_i) \leq \sup (x_i + \sup y_i) = \sup x_i + \sup y_i$. Of course, this works provided that you do not encounter  $\infty - \infty$, so you must take the usual precautions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the comments by Alex M: write $$A= \sup\left\{ \int_A   \operatorname{div} T \space \rm d m^d : T \in C_0^1(\mathbb{R}^d,\mathbb{R}^d), |T(x)| \le 1 \right\}$$
and
$$B = \sup\left\{ \int_{\mathbb{R}^d \setminus F}  \operatorname{div} T \space dm^d : T \in C_0^1(\mathbb{R}^d,\mathbb{R}^d),|T(x)| \le 1 \right\}$$
to shorten notation. Note that $A\ge 0$ and $B\ge 0$ because $T\equiv 0$ is one of eligible fields.

For every field $T \in C_0^1(\mathbb{R}^d,\mathbb{R}^d)$ such that $|T(x)| \le 1$ we have
$$
\int_A   \operatorname{div} T\, dm^d\le A\quad\text{and}\quad 
\int_{\mathbb{R}^d \setminus F}  \operatorname{div} T \, dm^d \le B
$$
hence
$$
\int_{A\cup (\mathbb{R}^d \setminus F)}   \operatorname{div} T\, dm^d\le A+ B
$$
Since $A+B$ is an upper bound for such integrals, it follows that their supremum (the *least* upper bound) is $\le A+B$.